# setOnFocusChangeListener re-add a hint

Tags: java, android

I have an `EditText` with a hint "20 character max" and when I click on it it disappear with a `setOnClickListener` and a `setHint` inside it.
But now I want to re-add the hint if the person doesn't put anything on it...

There is my code for now :

```
entry01.setOnFocusChangeListener(
            new OnFocusChangeListener() {
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                    prenom = entry01.getText().toString();
                    if(entry01.getText().toString().equals(""));
                            entry01.setHint("20 lettres max");
                }
            });

    entry01.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {


        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(entry01.getText().toString().equals(""))
                entry01.setHint("20 lettres max");
        }


        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {

        }


        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,int count) {
            if(entry01.getText().toString().equals(""))
                entry01.setHint("20 lettres max");
        }

    });
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Do it in `onTextChangeListener()`

Comment: The hint of a EditText will be hidden when they start typing and shown  if they delete the contents of the view.. what are trying to do which is different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
entry01.setOnFocusChangeListener(
new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        prenom = entry01.getText().toString();
        if(entry01.getText().toString().equals(""));
                entry01.setHint("20 lettres max"); // means "20 character max"
        }
    });
```

use

```
entry01.addtextchangelintener(new TextWatcher)
```

and then in ontext change lintener

```
if((start + count) > 0)
{ entry01.setHint("20 lettres max"); }
```

or you can use your code too

```
if(entry01.getText().toString().equals(""));
            entry01.setHint("20 lettres max"); // means "20 character max"
```

EDIT:

Do like this

```
receiverName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence paramCharSequence, int paramInt1,int paramInt2, int paramInt3) 
        {
            if((start + count) > 0)
            { entry01.setHint("20 lettres max"); }

            //if(entry01.getText().toString().equals(""));
          //  entry01.setHint("20 lettres max");
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence paramCharSequence,int paramInt1, int paramInt2, int paramInt3) {}

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable paramEditable) {}
    });
```

Comment: in place of your focus change listener use the code i mentioned right now, check the edit

Comment: Thank you it works !
It just "if(start + count) doesn't work so I put mine "if(entry01.getText.....)"

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention the params for ontextchanged are int start,int before, int count

but using your condition will work as well

Comment: yes yes I did care about start and before as params but even with that I got an error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to boolean" and to be honest I don't understand the syntax "(start + count)" ^^ 
Thanks again !

Comment: sorry again, its my mistake that is int and that should be if((start+count)>0)

I wrote the code here only so the datatype went completely out of my head